# Creating a custom validator as a service in Symfony2

Tags: validation, symfony, service

I'm trying to send an EntityManager object to my custom validator. For that, I created a service and defined the entity manager as an argument.

The problem is that the argument isn't sent to the validator, it fires an error in the __construct() function indicating that no arguments have been passed.

This is the definition of my service:

```
dinamic.shop.validator.deliverydate:
    class: Dinamic\ShopBundle\Validator\Constraints\DeliveryDateValidator
    arguments: 
        - @doctrine.orm.entity_manager
    tags:
        - { name: validator.constraint_validator, alias: deliverydate }
```

Here is the validateBy() method of my Constraint:

```
class DeliveryDate extends Constraints
{
    ...
    public function validateBy()
    {
        return 'deliverydate';
    }
}
```

Here is my ConstraintValidator:

Finally, this is how I set the constraint on the field. The field is not mapped to any entity:

```
->add('deliveryday', 'date', array(
                                'label' => 'Día de entrega',
                                'widget' => 'single_text',
                                'format' => 'dd/MM/yyyy',
                                'constraints' => array(
                                            new NotBlank(),
                                            new DeliveryDate($deliveryDateOptions),
                                                    ),
                                 )
)
```

I think that my error is in the FormType class, where I set the constraint on the field, but I can't find any examples of non-mapped fields.

I'm using Symfony2.3, any help will be appreciated, thanks a lot.

[EDIT]

I've used the command "sudo php app/console container:debug | grep validator" and the service I've created appears on the results

```
dinamic.shop.validator.deliverydate container Dinamic\ShopBundle\Validator\Constraints\DeliveryDateValidator
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error. The problem was the function 'validateBy', it should have been **validatedBy()**

So the only change I needed to do was to change said function.

Thank you for the help @Patt

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely one of those syntax issues!

The syntax can be this:

```
dinamic.shop.validator.deliverydate:
    class: Dinamic\ShopBundle\Validator\Constraints\DeliveryDateValidator
    arguments: [@doctrine.orm.entity_manager]
    tags:
        - { name: validator.constraint_validator, alias: deliverydate }
```

or this:

```
dinamic.shop.validator.deliverydate:
    class: Dinamic\ShopBundle\Validator\Constraints\DeliveryDateValidator
    arguments: 
        entityManager: "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
    tags:
        - { name: validator.constraint_validator, alias: deliverydate }
```

---

***Note:*** To check if the service you're passing exists:

```
php app/console container:debug | grep doctrine
```

Will give you:

```
....
doctrine.orm.entity_manager    n/a       alias for doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager
....
```

Comment: Sorry, but I've tried both syntax and neither of them worked. Also the console command outputs the service with the same name, so the argument name is correct. Also, I tried changing the 'class' parameter of the service to a non-existant one and nothing changed, so the service configuration isn't being used at all.